Bigger space than distribution space $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$?
Is there some reasonable and nice space which contains the space of distributions and is strictly bigger?
There are some easy measureable functions like $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^a}$ with $a \geq 1 $. These should be in some common space together with all distributions. Is this possible?

Look for ultradistributions.

@Jochen Do you have maybe a reference? I can't find any good sources.

Braun, R. W.; Meise, R.; Taylor, B. A.
Ultradifferentiable functions and Fourier analysis.
Result. Math. 17, No. 3-4, 206-237 might be a starting point.
